# Check if wind direction is within a specified range

Tags: language-agnostic, enums, discrete-mathematics

I am representing wind directions using integer values (an Enum) ranging from 0 for North, through to 15 for North-North-West.

I need to check if a given wind direction (integer value between 0 and 15) is within a certain range. I specify my `WindDirectionFrom` value first moving clockwise to `WindDirectionTo` to specify the range of allowable wind direction.

Obviously if `WindDirectionFrom=0` and `WindDirectionTo=4` (between N and E direction) and the wind direction is NE (2) the calculation is simply

```
int currentWindDirection = 2;
bool inRange = (WindDirectionFrom <= currentWindDirection && currentWindDirection <= WindDirectionTo); 
              //(0 <= 2 && 2 <= 4) simple enough...
```

However for a different case where say `WindDirectionFrom=15`, `WindDirectionTo=4` and wind direction is NE (2) again, the calculation immediately breaks...

```
bool inRange = (WindDirectionFrom <= currentWindDirection && currentWindDirection <= WindDirectionTo); 
              //(15 <= 2 && 2 <= 4) oops :(
```

I'm sure this can't be too difficult, but I'm having a real mental block with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
int normedDirection( int direction, int norm )
{
   return (NumberOfDirections + currentDirection - norm) % NumberOfDirections;
}

int normed = normedDirection( currentWindDirection, WindDirectionFrom );
bool inRange = (0 <= normed && normed <= normedDirection( WindDirectionTo, WindDirectionFrom );
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is modular arithmetic.  Do your arithmetic mod 16, and check to see if the difference is from (say) at least 14 (the modular equivalent of -2) or at most 2.

How to do modular arithmetic will vary between languages.  With C or C++, you would find x mod 16 as follows:

```
int xm = x % 16;
if (xm < 0) xm += 16;
```

(Thanks to msw for pointing out that arithmetic on `enum`s is frequently not allowed, and for good reasons.  An `enum` normally represents objects or conditions that are discrete and not related arithmetically.)

Comment: Aah right, well I'm using C# so I guess it's going to be pretty much the same syntax as you've got here.

Comment: Correct, except many languages won't allow arithmetic on enums (for good reason). The OP will have to get his enums into numerics.